# retrieving records from database by array of id's in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have stuck with a problem here, i want to retrieve records from a table with a condition as follows:

```
table:
ID    NAME        
1     name1
2     name2
3     name3 
4     name4
5     name5

$idlist = array(1,2,3,4);    

SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id='$idlist'
```

Unlike normal condition, i want to get all the records by using list of id's that $idlist array holds.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use implode function:

```
'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', $idlist) . ')'
```

Comment: Thanks @Serge simple and short. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN` keyword to achieve your goal

```
$idlist = array(1,2,3,4);    
$idlist_str = implode(",",$idlist);
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id IN ($idlist_str);
```

> See **[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)**
>
> See [**IN**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MYSQL **`IN`** Clause, it requires **comma separated ids.**
You need to convert you array into comma seprated by using

PHP **[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)**.

See **MYSQL** [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

```
$idlist = array(1,2,3,4);   
$IDs = implode(',',$idlist);
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id IN ('$idlist');
```

SQL Fiddle [**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50f60/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4)
```

please try this one